# Is the "radar bubble of two events" known by some other, more conventional name?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, terminology

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/44881) to a question concerning the intersection of [the future light cone of one event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone#Light-cones_in_general_relativity), and [the past light cone of another event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone#Light-cones_in_general_relativity) it was noted that the name

> *radar bubble* suggests itself

for referring to such an intersection (at least if this intersection is not the empty set, if the two events under consideration have accordingly a suitable [causal relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations) to each other).

A [plain web search for "*radar bubble*" along with "intersection" and "light cone"](https://www.google.cam/#q=%22radar+bubble%22+%22intersection%22+%22light+cone%22) suggests that this terminology is used only rarely (at present; while, surely, such intersections are discussed more frequently).

Therefore **my question**:
Do we perhaps have another, more conventional name for referring to the intersection of the future light cone of one event, and the past light cone of another event (in suitable causal relation to the first event) ?

Comment: It is sometimes referred to as the causal diamond due to its shape in two dimensions

Comment: @Slereah: "_It is sometimes referred to as the causal diamond_" -- Perhaps so; but this would not agree with the description of "causal diamond" as ["set of all events that lie in both the past of some point {...} and the future of some point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Causal_relations), as illustrated [here](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/causal-diamond.png). My question is to name the intersection of two **light cones**, where ["the future light cone of an event is the boundary of its causal future"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone), etc.

Comment: I (OP of linked answer) vote for radar bubble. :-)

Comment: @Retarded Potential: "_I (OP of linked answer) vote for radar bubble. :-)_" –- Alright. However, as user Slereah's comment above illustrates, "radar bubble (of two suitable events)" may easily be confused with "the causal diamond (of these two events)". I prefer to speak of the "**ping set** (of these two events)", or if applicable, their "**ping surface**". And I hope that this terminology catches on ...

Comment: That's actually pretty good, other than the obvious problem: that it was thought of by someone other than me.

Comment: I guess you mean the difference is that "ping set" includes cases such as the set is empty because the two events are spacelike separated?

Comment: @Retarded Potential: My objection to the term "_bubble_" is that it may not only be understood as "just the boundary" (as intended), but instead as "including the interior" (as Slereah apparently did). (And my objection to the term "_radar_" is that it wreaks of "coordinates" ... &). If we both expanded our suggestions into full-fledged answers then people could cast their votes ... ;).